# how to handle "getaddrinfo failed"?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, urlopen

Hallo, i have problem. i use mechanize, python 2.7 to connect some sites (the code is not important right now) i have list of sites and i connect to them one by now. When it happens the site from my list doesn't exist i get error:

> urllib2.URLError:  [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

I tried to handle it by doing this:

```
             except mechanize.URLError, e:
                    result = str(e.reason)
```

or

```
             except urllib2.URLError, e:
                    result = str(e.reason)
```

or even

```
             except Exception, e:
                    result = str(e)
```

But it just don't want to work.

How to solve this? When this error happens i just want to print something like "connection failed" and move to the next address on the list. How to catch this error by `except`?

Comment: what does "don't want to work" mean? do they call in sick? post tracebacks.

Comment: @SilentGhost I assume it means "doesn't catch", but even then `except Exception: ` would work. Python issue?

Comment: Note that you can do `except Foo as e` since you're on 2.7 -- nicer syntax backported from Python 3 :-)

Comment: Hey, I noticed you did'nt mark any answers as solved... I was wondering, were you able to fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Random guess but try:

```
import socket

try:
   ...
except socket.gaierror:
   pass
```

`socket.gaierror` is the `"[Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed"` error.

You can easily figure out the exception if you do

```
try:
    ...
except:
    import sys
    # prints `type(e), e` where `e` is the last exception
    print sys.exc_info()[:2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
except urrlib2.URLError:
    print "Connection failed"
    continue # NOTE: This assumes this is in a loop. If not, substitute for return
```

Most Python libraries tell you the type of the exception in the error report, in this case `urllib2.URLError`, so that is indeed what you `except` for.

However, if `except Exception:` is not working for you, you've got more serious problems than a user inputting a bad web address (assuming this is not urllib2's fault).

Comment: Old post, I know, but for any others who come across it, `urrlib2.URLError` is misspelt. It should be `urllib2.URLError` for Py2 (and `urllib.error.URLError` in Py3).