# How to properly handle multiple connection error exceptions on Python3? related to python-binance package

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, exception, python-requests, binance

I'm coding a little cryptocurrency tracker using the `python-binance` package version `1.0.16` (the last version as of today)

My problem appears at some specific part of the process which is the login to the Binance server through the `Client` using the **api and secret keys**. Here's the code for that:

```
from binance.Client import Client

api = input("Paste your API KEY here: ")
secret = input("Now paste your SECRET KEY here: ")

client = Client(api_key=api, api_secret=secret, tld = "com")
```

*Note: As long as the user has an stable internet connection, no exception is raised, allowing the tracker to work as expected*

But, if the user were not even connected to the internet (without obviously noticing it), the following exceptions would be thrown after executing the code above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 358, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020B4CEB4A00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/ping (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020B4CEB4A00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\user\.spyder-py3\btcusdt_only-signals.system.py", line 207, in <module>
    client = Client(api_key= api_key, api_secret= secret_key, tld= "com")

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 300, in __init__
    self.ping()

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 526, in ping
    return self._get('ping', version=self.PRIVATE_API_VERSION)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 371, in _get
    return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 334, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 314, in _request
    self.response = getattr(self.session, method)(uri, **kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 600, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 565, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/ping (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020B4CEB4A00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

So, in essence, there are 4 exceptions that need to be handled:

- `gaierror`
- `NewConnectionError`
- `MaxRetryError`
- `ConnectionError`

At first I tried the following code based on [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844933/16467154) because I thought that as `gaierror` was always the very first exception raised, *I supposed* that by correctly handling it, the rest of the exceptions would not be raised:

```
from binance.Client import Client
import socket

api = input("Paste your API KEY here: ")
secret = input("Now paste your SECRET KEY here: ")

while True:
    try: 
        client = Client(api_key= api_key, api_secret= secret_key, tld= "com")
        break
    except socket.gaierror:
        print("You are not connected to the internet, first make sure to be connected before executing this program")
        input("Once done, press Enter key:")
```

Unfortunately, my approach didn't handle anything and ended up throwing exactly the same output described above, with the same exceptions raised in the same order.

However, **this other one DID WORK**!:

```
from binance.Client import Client

api = input("Paste your API KEY here: ")
secret = input("Now paste your SECRET KEY here: ")

while True:
    try: 
        client = Client(api_key= api_key, api_secret= secret_key, tld= "com")
        break
    except Exception:
        print("You are not connected to the internet, first make sure to be connected before executing this program")
        input("Once done, press Enter key:")
```

So guys, I came here to know if there's a better way than just setting `except Exception` to handle the 4 exceptions raised? You know, it doesn't look very `Good Practices` to me, and also doesn't let me know exactly what's happening behind and how to explain the user why such thing is happening, so may you help me out here?

Comment: Catch the last exception is enough.  Others have been caught and were just printed like a call stack.

Comment: I just catched the last one and it didn't work either.

Comment: Since you asked how to import those exceptions, I guess that probably means the last exception is not caught actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your except blocks like so:

```py
from binance.Client import Client
import socket
from urllib3.exceptions import NewConnectionError, MaxRetryError, ConnectionError

api = input("Paste your API KEY here: ")
secret = input("Now paste your SECRET KEY here: ")

while True:
    try: 
        client = Client(api_key= api_key, api_secret= secret_key, tld= "com")
        break
    except (socket.gaierror, NewConnectionError, MaxRetryError, ConnectionError) as e:
        print("You are not connected to the internet, first make sure to be connected before executing this program")
        input("Once done, press Enter key:")
```

or

```py
    except gaierror as ge:
        print("something ge specific")
    except NewConnectionError as nce:
        print("something nce specific")
    # ...
```

With the latter approach, you can handle each error independently.
If you want to just filter out connection errors and deal with them in one batch, the first is a good option.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Seo, I tried that code and it threw that `NewConnectionError`, `MaxRetryError`, `ConnectionError` were not defined, may you please explain how could those exceptions be imported?

Comment: @NoahVerner Hello, may you please check the edited code? The specified exceptions are from urllib3

Comment: I just did, and unfortunately I got the same exceptions raised

Comment: `from urllib3.exceptions import NewConnectionError, MaxRetryError, ConnectionError` does this work without errors inside your virtual environment REPL?

Comment: It doesn't, it's weird since even though I'm importing the same exceptions the console throws and catching them in a single/several lines, it doesn't end up changing the undesired output.

Comment: Follow `File "F:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 565, in send raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)`  and check the actual exception package name. Or, when caught by wildcard `except Exception as e`, print `type(e)` to see the exception type.

Comment: In the end, I never found a better way to handle the exceptions in my case than what I initially did, but I decided to mark your reply as the solution because you tried it and showed a possible way. If someone else is experiencing the same issue, I suggest to go for my approach that **DID WORK**.

Answer (score 0):

it didn't work for me but **I made it work**. When something happens with you internet connection it will continue to try to connect. Script continues to work without any crashes.
Also "timeout" argument affects on how long it will wait until Exception.

```
import sys
from binance.client import Client
from binance.exceptions import BinanceAPIException, BinanceRequestException
from requests.exceptions import Timeout, ReadTimeout, ConnectTimeout, RetryError, HTTPError
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError as CError
import socket
from urllib3.exceptions import NewConnectionError, MaxRetryError, ConnectionError


config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
# create file config.ini and add your key there
api_key = config.get('keys', 'api_key')
api_secret = config.get('keys', 'api_secret')


while True:
    try:
        print('Trying to connect Binance Server')
        client = Client(api_key, api_secret, {"timeout": 10}, testnet=True)
        print("Using Binance TestNet Server")
    except (BinanceAPIException, BinanceRequestException) as Binance_Error:
        print('Binance Error Exception')
        continue
    except (socket.gaierror, NewConnectionError, MaxRetryError, ConnectionError) as Socket_Error:
        print('Socket Error Exception')
        continue
    except (Timeout, ReadTimeout, ConnectTimeout, RetryError, HTTPError, CError) as Conn_Error:
        print('Connection Error Exception')
        continue
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).